# Mongo/Mongoose Invalid atomic update value error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am trying to write to write an update to a Mongo document using the Mongoose findOneAndUpdate function. Essentially, I have a document that has an array of another Schema in it, and when I attempt to append more of those schema type, I get the following error:

```
[Error: Invalid atomic update value for $__. Expected an object, received object]
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out what this error even means, much less what its source is.

The data I'm attempting to update is as follows:

```
{ section_id: 51e427ac550dabbb0900000d,
version_id: 7,
last_editor_id: 51ca0c4b5b0669307000000e,
changelog: 'Added modules via merge function.',
committed: true,
_id: 51e45c559b85903d0f00000a,
__v: 0,
modules: 
[ { orderId: 0,
type: 'test',
tags: [],
data: [],
images: [],
content: ["Some Content Here"] },
{ orderId: 1,
type: 'test',
tags: [],
data: [],
images: [],
content: ["Some Content Here"] },
{ orderId: 2,
type: 'test',
tags: [],
data: [],
images: [],
content: ["Some Content Here"] },
{ orderId: 3,
type: 'test',
tags: [],
data: [],
images: [],
content: ["Some Content Here"] },
{ orderId: 4,
type: 'test',
tags: [],
data: [],
images: [],
content: ["Some Content Here"] },
{ orderId: 5,
type: 'test',
tags: [],
data: [],
images: [],
content: ["Some Content Here"] } ] }
```

The only difference is that when I retrieve it, there are three fewer modules, and I append some new ones to the array.

Would love to hear any thoughts, at least as to what the error means!

Answer (score 16):

This is probably because the updated object is still a Mongoose object.
Try to convert it to a JS object before the `findOneAndUpdate`

```
object = object.toString()
```

And delete any potential ID attribute

```
delete object._id
```

Or simply

```
object = object.toObject();
```

Comment: You can use .toObject() to convert a mongooseObject to an object

Comment: when you use .toObject() does it automatically remove the _id field ?

Comment: Thank you from 2020. Things are pretty bad in the world right now, but this comment helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it turned out I was using $push incorrectly. I was doing

```
{$push:thing_to_push}
```

But it needed to be

```
{$push:{list_to_push_into:thing_to_push}}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Magrelo and @plus led me to an answer that worked. Something like:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({ section_id: '51e427ac550dabbb0900000d' }, mongooseObject.toObject(), { upsert: true }, function(err, results) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: mongooseObject.toObject()
this is what helped, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try passing update parameter value as string instead of mongoose model object. I was getting same error when I use to pass model object. Below is the code difference.

Code that was having issue:

```
updateUser: function(req, res) {
**var updatedUserModel = new Users(req.body);**
    Users.findOneAndUpdate({tpx_id:req.params.id}, {$set:**updatedUserModel**}, function(err, User){
           ...
   }
}
```

Working code:

```
updateUser: function(req, res) {
   Users.findOneAndUpdate({tpx_id:req.params.id}, {$set:**req.body**}, function(err, User) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up by using [finOne() method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

create a new one if no found, update the existing one if found.

I know there are two operations. but I just haven't find any way to do it in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is if you are sending passing an array of changes to $set.  The error message that I received when calling something like this:

```
db.products.update( { sku: "abc123" },
                { $set: [
                         {quantity: 500},
                         {instock: true}
                        ]
                }
              )
```

Gave me the [Error: Invalid atomic update value for $set. Expected an object, received object]

Changing it to an object worked.

```
db.products.update( { sku: "abc123" },
                { $set: {
                          quantity: 500,
                          instock: true
                        }
                }
              )
```